# Deserializing JSON and converting them to C# objects

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a silverlight web application. From this app I am making a call to JSP pages using `WebClient` class. Now JSP returns a response in JSON format

```
{
 "results":[{"Value":"1","Name":"Advertising"},
 {"Value":"2","Name":"Automotive Expenses"},{"Value":"3","Name":"Business Miscellaneous"}]
}
```

The above response is assigned to my Stream object.

I have a c# class CategoryType

```
public class CategoryType
{
 public string Value{get;set;}
 public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

My aim is to convert the reponses in to `Collection<CategoryType>` and use it in my C# Code

As of now I am trying to use `DataContractJSONSerialiser`. But not sure if there is an easy and efficent way to do this. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does the web service support any other output besides JSON? Is there a wsdl for it?

Comment: @Marc There is no webservice here. My silverlight web application calls a .jsp page using WebClient class and the .jsp return a JSON of the format mentioned above. But I am not sure on how to convert that JSON to a Collection<CategoryType>

Answer (score 2):

Its JSON and to convert it to object you need to deserialize it to object. many tools are available from Microsoft and Third party .

And you seem to be going the right way.

I have used [`JavascriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx). See its use here http://shekhar-pro.blogspot.com/2011/01/serializing-and-deserializing-data-from.html

or use a great library [JSON.Net](http://json.net/) used extensively even before Microsoft released those libraries.

**Update**

As you mentioned in your comments you want to convert it to Collection you could do it like this:

create array class to represent array of items.

```
public class CategoryTypeColl
{
     public CategoryType[] results {get;set;}
}
```

and in your code

```
Collection<CategoryType> ctcoll = new Collection<CategoryType>();
JavaScriptSerializer jsr = new  JavaScriptSerializer();
CategoryTpeColl ctl = jsr.Deserialize<CategoryTypeColl>(/*your JSON String*/);
List<CategoryType> collection = (from item in ctl.results
                                select item).ToList();
//If you have implemented Icollection then you can use yourcollection and Add items in a foreach loop.
```